# Cosmos DB: The request failed because the client was unable to establish connections to 1 endpoints across 1 regions

Tags: azure-functions, azure-cosmosdb

Below exception logged in the application insights for HTTP Trigger Azure function.

**The request failed because the client was unable to establish connections to 1 endpoints across 1 regions. The client CPU was overloaded during the attempted request**

> "outerId":"0","message":"Response status code does not indicate
> success: ServiceUnavailable (503); Substatus: 0; ActivityId:
> 35d16569-41da-42ed-bc5c-8f9a5c49078e; Reason: (The request failed
> because the client was unable to establish connections to 1 endpoints
> across 1 regions. The client CPU was overloaded during the attempted
> request.\r\nActivityId: 35d16569-41da-42ed-bc5c-8f9a5c49078e, Please
> see CosmosDiagnostics, Windows/10.0.14393
> cosmos-netstandard-sdk/3.9.0);","parsedStack":[{"assembly":"Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Client,
> Version=3.9.1.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35","method":"Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.ResponseMessage.EnsureSuccessStatusCode","level":0,"line":0},{"assembly":"Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Client,
> Version=3.9.1.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35","method":"Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.ReadFeedResponse`1.CreateResponse","level":1,"line":0},{"assembly":"Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Client, Version=3.9.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35","method":"Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.FeedIteratorCore`1+d__6.MoveNext","level":2,"line":0},{"assembly":"System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e","method":"System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw","level":3,"line":0},{"assembly":"System.Private.CoreLib,
> Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e","method":"System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess","level":4,"line":0},{"assembly":"FleetHub.Notifications.Domain,
> Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=null","method":"FleetHub.Notifications.Domain.Repositories.CosmosDBRepository`1+<GetItemsAsync>d__10.MoveNext","level":5,"line":0},{"assembly":"System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e","method":"System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw","level":6,"line":0},{"assembly":"System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e","method":"System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess","level":7,"line":0},{"assembly":"System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e","method":"System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification","level":8,"line":0},{"assembly":"FleetHub.Notifications.Queries, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null","method":"FleetHub.Notifications.Queries.Handlers.RetrieveNotificationQueryHandler+<GetNotifications>d__4.MoveNext","level":9,"line":41,"fileName":"D:\\a\\144\\s\\FleetHub.Notifications.Queries\\Handlers\\RetrieveNotificationQueryHandler.cs"},{"assembly":"System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e","method":"System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw","level":10,"line":0},{"assembly":"System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e","method":"System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess","level":11,"line":0},{"assembly":"System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e","method":"System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification","level":12,"line":0},{"assembly":"FleetHub.Notifications.Queries, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null","method":"FleetHub.Notifications.Queries.Handlers.RetrieveNotificationQueryHandler+<GetNotificationSummary>d__5.MoveNext","level":13,"line":54,"fileName":"D:\\a\\144\\s\\FleetHub.Notifications.Queries\\Handlers\\RetrieveNotificationQueryHandler.cs"},{"assembly":"System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e","method":"System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw","level":14,"line":0},{"assembly":"System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e","method":"System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess","level":15,"line":0},{"assembly":"System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e","method":"System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification","level":16,"line":0},{"assembly":"FleetHub.Notifications.Queries, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null","method":"FleetHub.Notifications.Queries.Handlers.RetrieveNotificationQueryHandler+<HandleAsync>d__3.MoveNext","level":17,"line":28,"fileName":"D:\\a\\144\\s\\FleetHub.Notifications.Queries\\Handlers\\RetrieveNotificationQueryHandler.cs"},{"assembly":"System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e","method":"System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw","level":18,"line":0},{"assembly":"System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e","method":"System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess","level":19,"line":0},{"assembly":"System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e","method":"System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification","level":20,"line":0},{"assembly":"FleetHub.Notifications.Azure.Functions, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null","method":"FleetHub.Notifications.Azure.Functions.Notifications.RetrieveNotifications+<Run>d__0.MoveNext","level":21,"line":39,"fileName":"D:\\a\\144\\s\\FleetHub.Notifications.Azure.Functions\\Notifications\\RetrieveNotifications.cs"},{"assembly":"System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e","method":"System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw","level":22,"line":0},{"assembly":"System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e","method":"System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess","level":23,"line":0},{"assembly":"System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e","method":"System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification","level":24,"line":0},{"assembly":"System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e","method":"System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult","level":25,"line":0},{"assembly":"Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host,
> Version=3.0.23.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35","method":"Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionInvoker`2+<InvokeAsync>d__10.MoveNext","level":26,"line":52,"fileName":"C:\\projects\\azure-webjobs-sdk-rqm4t\\src\\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\\Executors\\FunctionInvoker.cs"},{"assembly":"System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e","method":"System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw","level":27,"line":0},{"assembly":"System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e","method":"System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess","level":28,"line":0},{"assembly":"System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e","method":"System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification","level":29,"line":0},{"assembly":"System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e","method":"System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult","level":30,"line":0},{"assembly":"Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host,
> Version=3.0.23.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35","method":"Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionExecutor+FunctionInvocationFilterInvoker+d__10.MoveNext","level":31,"line":1116,"fileName":"C:\projects\azure-webjobs-sdk-rqm4t\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Executors\FunctionExecutor.cs"},{"assembly":"System.Private.CoreLib,
> Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e","method":"System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw","level":32,"line":0},{"assembly":"Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host,
> Version=3.0.23.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35","method":"Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionExecutor+FunctionInvocationFilterInvoker+d__10.MoveNext","level":33,"line":1154,"fileName":"C:\projects\azure-webjobs-sdk-rqm4t\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Executors\FunctionExecutor.cs"},{"assembly":"System.Private.CoreLib,
> Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e","method":"System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw","level":34,"line":0},{"assembly":"System.Private.CoreLib,
> Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e","method":"System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess","level":35,"line":0},{"assembly":"System.Private.CoreLib,
> Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e","method":"System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification","level":36,"line":0},{"assembly":"System.Private.CoreLib,
> Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e","method":"System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult","level":37,"line":0},{"assembly":"Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host,
> Version=3.0.23.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35","method":"Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionExecutor+d__27.MoveNext","level":38,"line":547,"fileName":"C:\projects\azure-webjobs-sdk-rqm4t\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Executors\FunctionExecutor.cs"},{"assembly":"System.Private.CoreLib,
> Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e","method":"System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw","level":39,"line":0},{"assembly":"System.Private.CoreLib,
> Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e","method":"System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess","level":40,"line":0},{"assembly":"System.Private.CoreLib,
> Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e","method":"System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification","level":41,"line":0},{"assembly":"System.Private.CoreLib,
> Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e","method":"System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult","level":42,"line":0},{"assembly":"Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host,
> Version=3.0.23.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35","method":"Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionExecutor+d__26.MoveNext","level":43,"line":492,"fileName":"C:\projects\azure-webjobs-sdk-rqm4t\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Executors\FunctionExecutor.cs"},{"assembly":"System.Private.CoreLib,
> Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e","method":"System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw","level":44,"line":0},{"assembly":"System.Private.CoreLib,
> Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e","method":"System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess","level":45,"line":0},{"assembly":"System.Private.CoreLib,
> Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e","method":"System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification","level":46,"line":0},{"assembly":"System.Private.CoreLib,
> Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e","method":"System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult","level":47,"line":0},{"assembly":"Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host,
> Version=3.0.23.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35","method":"Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionExecutor+d__25.MoveNext","level":48,"line":438,"fileName":"C:\projects\azure-webjobs-sdk-rqm4t\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Executors\FunctionExecutor.cs"},{"assembly":"System.Private.CoreLib,
> Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e","method":"System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw","level":49,"line":0},{"assembly":"System.Private.CoreLib,
> Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e","method":"System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess","level":50,"line":0},{"assembly":"System.Private.CoreLib,
> Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e","method":"System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification","level":51,"line":0},{"assembly":"System.Private.CoreLib,
> Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e","method":"System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult","level":52,"line":0},{"assembly":"Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host,
> Version=3.0.23.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35","method":"Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionExecutor+d__19.MoveNext","level":53,"line":245,"fileName":"C:\projects\azure-webjobs-sdk-rqm4t\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Executors\FunctionExecutor.cs"}],"type":"Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.CosmosException","id":"23479096"}]

Azure Function:

```
public static class RetrieveNotifications
    {
        [FunctionName(nameof(RetrieveNotifications))]
        public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
            [Inject] ILoggingService loggingService,
            [Inject] IQueryValidator queryValidator,
            [Inject] IQueryHandler<RetrieveNotificationQuery, NotificationSummaryResponse> queryHandler)
        {
            var logger = new Logger(loggingService);

            try
            {
                logger.Info($"Retrieve Notifications request received on {nameof(RetrieveNotifications)}");

                IActionResult actionResult = null;

                string requestBody = await new StreamReader(req.Body).ReadToEndAsync();

                var query = requestBody.AsPoco<RetrieveNotificationQuery>();

                if (queryValidator.Validate<RetrieveNotificationQuery>(req, query, new RetrieveNotificationQueryValidator(), logger, ref actionResult))
                {
                    var response = await queryHandler.HandleAsync(query, logger);
                    actionResult = new OkObjectResult(response);
                }
                return actionResult;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                logger.Error($"Exception while processing {nameof(RetrieveNotifications)}", ex,
                nameof(RetrieveNotifications));

                throw;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

```
var options = new CosmosClientOptions() { ConnectionMode = ConnectionMode.Gateway };

var client = new CosmosClient(endpoint, key, options);
```

This works for me.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: ConnectionMode.Gateway is the default connection mode, so the above code to explicitly set it is not required

Comment: this worked for me too, can't find any official documentation to support that this matters but definitely not the default, without it , it doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 1):

Your exception contains the source of the connectivity problem:

```
The client CPU was overloaded during the attempted request
```

This means that CPU was starved and could not handle TCP requests within the expected timeout interval. It is within the official documentation causes: https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/cosmos-db/troubleshoot-dot-net-sdk-request-timeout#high-cpu-utilization

Check your instance metrics and see if you need to scale the size of the instances to handle the load of operations you are doing.
I see you are injecting references into the Function, I guess these are Singleton instances of the CosmosClient (if not, they should be).

Comment: Should I use singleton instance for all injected services in azure function?

Comment: But we're already using Singleton instance for CosmosClient

Comment: Then that's great. But something is drawing your CPU hot, either because the work you are processing is too much for the machine size or you are using the same App Service to share it across many Functions that are also firing. I would take a look at the App Service instance metrics, particularly CPU, and check the MAX during the time when these exceptions happen, as the link suggests.

Comment: I have checked, both CPU and Memory percentage is above 80%. We're using P2v2:2 app service plan.

Comment: That is rather high and potentially can impact TCP communication as the documentation explains. My recommendation is to investigate what is driving the CPU that high and either improve it (reduce CPU consumption) or if normal operations are expected to have this load, scale the instance size.

Comment: Just want to understand - if I increase instance count 2 to 4 in the app service plan, then will it impact CPU usage?

Comment: The problem is CPU usage. If my adding more instances you decrease the CPU usage because your load is more distributed, then that is one solution. You can also make the instances bigger or work on optimizing the code to reduce CPU usage. Whatever course you decide to take is valid as long as you lower the CPU consumption that is causing the TCP timeouts.

Comment: After increasing the instances count, I could see CPU usages percentage is going down but memory percentages is still high above 80%.

Comment: Do you still see the original exception across instances?

Comment: Then please file a support ticket, and make sure to include the complete stack trace of the latest exceptions. This really is beyond the scope of SO. If the exception still says CPU is overloaded, then that would still be the source.

Comment: Thanks! for your support, I'll raise a ticket for the same.